# Compile Module and Main Program In the Same File Using GFortran?

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran

I am new to fortran and I have this fortran90 program I am trying to run where the module and the main are in the same file called main.f90:

```
module real_precision
    implicit none

    integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(1)
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)

end module real_precision

program main_program

    use real_precision

    implicit none

    real(sp) :: a = 1.0_sp
    real(dp) :: b = 1.0_dp

    print *, a
    print *, b

end program main_program
```

And I compiled it once doing:

```
gfortran main.f90 -o main.x
```

Then run it:

```
./main.x
```

However I made a change to the module and saved it but compiling and running it this same way provides the same output which leads me to think that the module needs to be compiled? How do I compile both where they're in the same file? I could make the module a separate file but I'd like to know how to do it this way!

Comment: Having a module in a main program is a bit strange, but OK. It should be OK to compile the file even when you only changed something  in the module. What did you change, why do you think it didn't work, which command to compile did you use? Which version of gfortran?

Comment: @albert I'm just playing around with fortran, I just changed the line that read: integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(6) to integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(3). Changing the 6 to a 3. I was expecting when I compiled and ran it for it to output 3 significant figures instead of 6? But it just outputs the exact same thing. Perhaps I'm understanding it wrong. I'm using version 9.1.0 of gfortran!

Comment: If you want to know the possible values of `selected_real_kind(k)`, you can either use a loop and print the values, or use the constant array `real_kinds` in the `iso_fortran_env` module. On a usual personal computer, you should get two or three different values (32 bits IEEE 754, 64 bits IEEE 754, and an extended precision that may be based on 128 bits IEEE 754 or "[double-double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic)" encoding, or possibly 10-byte reals on x86).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected_real_kind(p)` returns the kind parameter of a real with precision *at least* `p` digits (if one exists).  It does not give a kind parameter for a real with exactly that precision.

If your compiler has does not have a real with precision less than `q` then `selected _real_kind(q)` and `selected_real_kind(q-1)` will not return different kind parameters.